# Trying to enable Github post commit hook with jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, hook

My objective is to build a project on jenkins when a push occurs on a specific (private) github repo.
For that i'm using the github plugin and the git post commit hook

Here the jenkins hook url
(https://jenkins.toto.com/github-webhook)

But i'm stuck !
I mark the "GitHub hook trigger for GitSCM polling" in my build, i setup the GitHub server in "Configure options" (the test connection return me: Credentials verified for user). I setup the 'Git' mark on "Source Code Management".

On github i add the Webhooks on the settings of the repo.
But some errors occurs, The first is that the "GitHub Hook Log" catch some builds but not all ans he gave me an error:

```
git ls-remote -h ssh://git@github.com/toto/repo # timeout=10
FATAL: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git@github.com/toto/repo" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The other error came from the Git setup of "Source Code Management" section in the configuration of the build.
The repository URL return me:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://github.com/toto/repo/ HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/toto/repo/
```

And i cant add Credentials on the "Credentials" line.

I try a lot of tutorial on the internet but thats not the good version or my configuration never match with their tutorial...

Need help please